# Numerous Activities in an app

Tags: android, android-intent

I just started learning Android App Development recently and I'm curious about this;
Suppose I want to make an app with  lots of activities(pages)  for example a Bible app with around 1189 chapters with Each chapters having different activities. Does that Mean I will  create about 1189 different activities or is there an easier way to create this type of app?

Comment: You wouldnt be creating an activity for each page as that would be an overkill.  Most of the data (text,  page number) would be loaded from a database,  text file or some other source.  In terms of quizzes or some sort of game related to each chapter would depend on what you want to achieve and how much can of the logic can be reused. Read up on Object Oriented Programming and Fragments.

Comment: One activity is enough. Unless you need a Splash Screen as well. All the rest is done in Fragments. And dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of design patterns. You can put the information you want to display in an class. Then you could span 1189 objects. You could create just one activity, and get 1189 different objects' information. Finally display in activity.

like this https://github.com/newcaoguo/booksource/tree/master/chapter3/RecyclerViewTest